# Azure Pipelines in Enterprise Github

Tags: github, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, enterprise

Folks, I've been trying to setup/Integrate Azure Pipelines on to our Enterprise Github. I know currently it does support only that of github.com.

If anyone indeed able to do the same, I'd need some pointers on the same.

Thank You All in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VSTS does support Github Enterprise:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/jan-24-vsts#build-with-continuous-integration-from-github-enterprise

You need to make sure VSTS servers and agents can access your GHE server, of course.

You can create a new Github Enterprise connection by going to 
"Project Settings" -> "Pipelines" -> "Service connections" -> "+ New service connection" -> "Github Enterprise"

[image: How to add Github Enterprise service connection]

Comment: Thanks for the reply Devstr. As VSTS has been rebranded to Azure Devops, I couldnt see the "GitHub Enterprise" option anywhere. May be its the new UI or am i missing something here?

Comment: updated the answer with location and screenshot of how to add new Github Enterprise connection.

Comment: Awesome. This answers my question. Thanks much.